# Interpreting classification model results

Tags: machine-learning, twitter, neural-network, svm, text-mining

I've been working on a text classification problem for a long while now and I'm having a problem interpreting the results and where to go next.

I've been working on tweets trying to classify if they are violent or not.

the results that are

for a dataset of size 1763 (pos: 214, neg: 1549) training is 1234 (pos : 152, neg : 1082) AND TEST set 529 (pos: 62, neg: 469)

the AUC scores on test set with BOW features 
SVM: 0.69
LR: 0.67
1 layer NN: 0.69

I can't interpret in terms of if the problem is in having or data or changing the model. I think as the different models give similar results it means that I need more data with better quality and more positive examples.

I also don't know what should I do next.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problems interpreting your results, you might try different metrics to evaluate the quality of your classification. For example, you could try accuracy, precision, recall and f1-score. After interpreting results and deciding which metric you would like to focus on, you could explore different strategies to improve it - for example, adding more data, performing hyper parameter tuning and/or trying different models. This book chapter discusses text classification evaluation and might help you: [Evaluation of text classification](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/evaluation-of-text-classification-1.html). Thanks